# TYPO3 tx_newscalendar / tt_news - Display links in listView

Tags: typo3, tt-news

A RTE link of a newsitem was not shown in tt_news List. I could get it displayed with this TS for tt_news

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList {
    content_stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
}

#or

plugin.tt_news {
   general_stdWrap.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc_RTE
}
```

Both methods appear in the [Ext Manual](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/tt_news/2.5.0/view/1/7/). And that's the point, nothing like this in the [Ext Manual](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/newscalendar/2.1.6/view/4/1/) of tx_newscalendar. )-:

I have some News which are displayed with tt_news fe plugin.

But on another page i need to display the news with tx_newscalendar fe plugin.
I can not find a solution to get the same thing work with newscalendar. I hoped that parseFunc for newscalendar inherits from tt_news, but not.

I tried something like this which is displayed in ts objectbrowser

```
plugin.tx_newscalendar_pi1
   listView.content_stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
}
```

but links are display like this in sourcecode:

```
<link htpp:mydomainde="" />Mysite</link>
```

Why **htpp:**, this looks realy rare?

plugin.tx_newscalendar_pi1.render.parserFunction which could be found in the [Ext Manual](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/newscalendar/2.1.6/view/4/1/) of the plugin is just for htmlentities, not for  parseFunc_RTE.

Does somebody know, how to show links in newscalendar list?

---

Comment: Glad that you solved your own problem, there's tip: you should post an answer for your own question instead editing the question. That way you'll be able to mark the answer as accepted and the question will be visible at Stack as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, sometimes it's typologic ;-)

I get the same result like for tt_news above with:

```
plugin.tx_newscalendar_pi1 {
    listView.subheader_stdWrap.parseFunc < lib.parseFunc_RTE
}
```

I saw in the calendar list template, that tx_newscalendar gets it's content with marker subheader ... and so it works with overriding the stdWrap for it.

So the problem is solved.